# Pendulum in Unity, sync with system clock (seconds)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, euler-angles, pendulum

I have to make a Pendulum sync with system time.
It has to be right in the middle of the swing when the second ticks in the clock.

I made this script, but its not sync.. it swings ok, but it depends on when I click play if its sync or not, and thats not ok.
It has to be with the system clock:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwingPendulo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pendulum;
    public float amplitude = 45f; 
    public float speed = 180f; 

    private float initialAngle; // Start angle

    private void Start()
    {
        initialAngle = pendulum.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Obtain actual time in seconds
        float currentTime = Time.time;

        // calculate actual pendulum angle
        float angle = initialAngle + Mathf.Sin(currentTime * speed * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * amplitude;

        // Rotate pendulum in Z
        pendulum.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle);

        // If we are between seconds, adjunst angle to half
        if (Mathf.Abs(angle - initialAngle) < 0.1f)
        {
            float halfAmplitude = amplitude / 2f;
            pendulum.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, initialAngle + halfAmplitude);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Time.time` is relative to application start. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html. I'd rework your code to start with `DateTime.Now`. And maybe use `.Ticks` mod 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

> This is the time in seconds since the start of the application, which `Time.timeScale` scales and `Time.maximumDeltaTime` adjusts.

In order to access your actual system time instead you could use [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now)

```
private Quaternion initialRotation;

private void Start()
{
    initialRotation = pendulum.rotation;
}

private void Update()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    // increases from 0 up to 2 (exclusive)
    // instead of reaching 2 restarts from 0
    var currentTime = now.Second % 2 + now.Millisecond / 1000f;

    // is 0 for exact seconds (0 and 1)
    // is 1 for 0.5 seconds
    // is -1 for 1.5 seconds
    var angle = Mathf.Sin(currentTime * 180f * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * amplitude;

    // Rotate pendulum in local Z
    pendulum.rotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle);
}
```